# Terminology: Product of numerator and denominator of rational number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, fractions, rational-numbers

I cannot find the correct terminology for the following:

Let $r=\frac{a}{b}$ with $a$,$b \in \mathbb{N}$ and coprime. I define $q=a\cdot b$. How is $q$ called?

I know that one can order rational numbers using the product of their nominator and denominator, but how is the product called? Order of the rational number? I was not able to locate a creditable source. Thanks

**Edit:**
I would like to say a sentence such as "q is the $x$ of the rational number r." - what is $x$?

Comment: Not well defined unless $(p,q)=1$ by the way

Comment: There is no $q$. I think you mean $a,b$ should be coprime. I added that.

Comment: I am **not sure at all** – but would it be sensible to call $p$ a sort of »height« of $r$. There is a height function $ H(r) := \max \{ |a|,|b|\} $ (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Height_function). Of course your definition is not the same but maybe something that serves a similar purpose?

Comment: @puck29 great thanks, it is indeed related, but as you said it's not the answer yet.

Comment: I think there is no standard name for this. So make something up and define it for your reader.

Comment: If someone has coined the term, then it doesn't seem to have come into wide usage, so feel free to invent your own. (If/when you publish your research, perhaps your editor will have seen an alternative.) Clearly, a web search for, say, "numerator", "denominator", "product" will not be at all helpful here. However, you could search for notions related to the purpose you have in mind; that is, look for papers, articles, even blog posts about the specific type of problem you're trying to solve. If this numerator-denominator product figured into that work, the authors likely had to name it, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an algorithm depending on two parameters $a$ and $b$, you may define the *multiplicative size* of your entry as the product $ab$. You could perhaps use the same term in your case.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunatly "multiplicative size" has no relation to the number "r". I want to say a sentence like "q is the XXX of the rational number r."

Comment: I disagree: $a$ and $b$ (and hence $q = ab$) are entirely determined by $r$. Remember that, according to your definition, $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Comment: Agreeing that @J.-E.Pin's "multiplicative size" is well-defined since the assumption is that the fraction $r$ is reduced.  It is true, though, that distinct fractions can have the same multiplicative size, such as 1/6, 2/3, and 3/2.